# Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: html, json, asp.net-mvc, error500

Espero me puedan apoyar, ya llevo varias semanas atorada con éste error

Tengo una aplicación en Visual Studio, en ASP.NET MVC, la cual sube registros de un excel a la base de datos (una carga masiva). Todo sale bien al correrlo desde Visual Studio, si hace la carga de la información. Lo publiqué y lo subí al servidor IIS, después, abro la página desde cualquier navegador y se visualiza bien, pero al momento de mandar la información a la base de datos, me manda dos errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que estuve investigando, eso pasa cuando la respuesta está en html y no pasa como Json, pero lo que me causa confusion es que desde Visual Studio si funciona.

Yo siento que el problema puede ser al consultar la bd o al mandar la información, pero no sé muy bien cual sería la solución. A continuación pongo partes de mi código...

**HomeController**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EnviarDatos([FromForm] IFormFile ArchivoExcel)
{
    // Se realiza conexión con la base de datos, se consultan los registros de la tabla Tb_Diseños y se guarda la información recibida en un datatable
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Server=NombreDelServidor; DataBase=DB_ControlProduccionPROD; user id=***; password=***; Trusted_Connection=True; TrustServerCertificate=True;");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDA;
    cnn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Tb_Diseños;";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sqlDA.Fill(dataTable);

    // Se crea una lista con los registros guardados en el datatable
    List<VMOrdenes> listDB = new List<VMOrdenes>();
    listDB = (from DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows
              select new VMOrdenes()
              {
                  Diseño_Itemnumber = dr["Diseño_Itemnumber"].ToString(),
                  Diseño_Productname = dr["Diseño_Productname"].ToString()
              }).ToList();

    Stream stream = ArchivoExcel.OpenReadStream();
    IWorkbook? myExcel = null;

    if (Path.GetExtension(ArchivoExcel.FileName) == ".xlsx")
    {
        myExcel = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
    }
    else
    {
        myExcel = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
    }

    ISheet hojaExcel = myExcel.GetSheetAt(0);

    int cantidadFilas = hojaExcel.LastRowNum;

    List<Ordenes>? listOrders = new List<Ordenes>();

    // Se crea una lista con la información del documento de excel
    for (int i = 1; i <= cantidadFilas; i++)
    {
        IRow fila = hojaExcel.GetRow(i);
        listOrders.Add(new Ordenes
        {
            Diseño_Itemnumber = fila.GetCell(0).ToString(),
            Diseño_Productname = fila.GetCell(1).ToString()
        });
    }

    // Se crea una nueva lista, la cual tiene como items el resultado de la comparación de la lista creada por la bd y la creada por el excel, insertando registros no duplicados.
    List<Ordenes> listFinal = listOrders.ExceptBy(listDB.Select(x => x.Diseño_Itemnumber), x => x.Diseño_Itemnumber).ToList();

    _dbContext.BulkInsert(listFinal);

    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new { mensaje = "La carga masiva se ejecutó con éxito"});
}
```

**Index**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"> Cargar Excel</div>
            <div class="card-body">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input class="form-control-file" type="file" id="inputExcel" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="mostrarDatos()">Mostrar Datos</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="enviarDatos()">Enviar Datos a BD</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr />

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="tbData" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item Number</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
        function mostrarDatos(){
            const input = document.getElementById("inputExcel")
            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append("ArchivoExcel", input.files[0])
            fetch("Home/MostrarDatos", {
                method: "POST",
                body:formData
            })
            .then((response) => { return response.json()})
            .then((dataJson) => {
                    
                console.log({ dataJson })
                dataJson.forEach((item) => {
                    $("#tbData tbody").append(
                        $("<tr>").append(
                            $("<td>").text(item.diseño_Itemnumber),
                            $("<td>").text(item.diseño_Productname)
                        )
                    )
                })
            })
        }
    
        function enviarDatos(){
            const input = document.getElementById("inputExcel")
            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append("ArchivoExcel",input.files[0])
            fetch("Home/EnviarDatos", {
                method: "POST",
                body:formData
            })
            .then((response) => { return response.json()})
            .then((dataJson) => {
                alert(dataJson.mensaje);
            })
        }
</script>
```

_Layout y Error

```
<!DOCTYPE html> //Aquí marca el error
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Error - gbrx.orders.uploadData</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css?v=AKvNjO3dCPPS0eSU1Ez8T2wI280i08yGycV9ndytL-c" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/gbrx.orders.uploadData.styles.css?v=TAjKCzPZnZ9166B1kUt6P--yJE53f0t2gg5IoO4sRg0" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav b-bvnkk8e8pf class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div b-bvnkk8e8pf class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> GBRX SAH - Items Ordenes de Producción </a>
                <button b-bvnkk8e8pf class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span b-bvnkk8e8pf class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div b-bvnkk8e8pf class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <!--
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div b-bvnkk8e8pf class="container">
        <main b-bvnkk8e8pf role="main" class="pb-3">
            
<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>

    <p>
        <strong>Request ID:</strong> <code>00-5147d4b5d88e3f99282c7a9572b3d521-3e921600dc696406-00</code>
    </p>

<h3>Development Mode</h3>
<p>
    Swapping to <strong>Development</strong> environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
</p>
<p>
    <strong>The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications.</strong>
    It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users.
    For local debugging, enable the <strong>Development</strong> environment by setting the <strong>ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT</strong> environment variable to <strong>Development</strong>
    and restarting the app.
</p>

        </main>
    </div>

    <footer b-bvnkk8e8pf class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div b-bvnkk8e8pf class="container">
            &copy; 2023 - gbrx.orders.uploadData - <a href="/Home/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/site.js?v=4q1jwFhaPaZgr8WAUSrux6hAuh0XDg9kPS3xIVq36I0"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Y te fijaste cuál es el contenido de ese HTML en la consola del navegador?

Comment: @padaleiana Sí, le doy clic en dónde dice VM26:1 y me manda el código que tengo en mi vista _Layout.cshtml y Error_cshtml, puse el código en la publicación.

Comment: ¿Leíste lo que te indica el mensaje de error?

Comment: Tienes un error en el `IActionResult` y como no tienes `try/catch` te arroja la página genérica de error. El motivo del error pueden ser muchos en tu caso, desde la conexión a la BD, que el archivo que estas enviando sea muy grande, que no tengas permisos para escribir en la carpeta o alguna incompatibilidad con la librería para generar excel, entre otros muchos

Comment: @padaleiana Al darle clic en el error 500, me lleva al fetch("Home/MostrarDatos" y al fetch("Home/EnviarDatos". Al dar clic en el error Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON, me manda al html de la vista _Layout y señala ésta parte <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Esa no era mi pregunta: ¿leíste el párrafo donde dice _Swapping to_...?